# How to use discord-rpc with GMS 2?

Tags: c++, game-maker

I want to add Discord Rich Presence to my game using [discord-rpc](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-rpc) but I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Did you try searching online how to add external libraries to game-maker?

Comment: I don't want to pay 10 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/2_interface/1_editors/extensions.html) page GMS 2 can use DLLs on Windows, SO-files on Linux and DyLib files on Mac.

So, what I'd suggest is creating a DLL in C++ that offers easy-to-use functions that you can call from your GMS scripts. You could probably try to also expose the whole Discord RPC SDK as a DLL, but I feel like you might be better off simply creating a wrapper around it, since the SDK relies on pointers, and I'm not sure how you'd use those in GMS scripts. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkgMxrDvwPs) I found about creating a DLL to be used with GMS.

This is a little hard given that the SDK uses callbacks for some stuff, but if all you want to do is to display information about the game in the user's Discord profile, this is actually quite easy to do, as you can ignore the callbacks. Just create a high-level function that sets the details in `DiscordRichPresence` like you want and then passes it to `Discord_UpdatePresence`.

Comment: There is a DLL version of discord-rpc library. Can you use it without problems? I don't know C++, that's why I asked here.

Comment: I have zero experience with discord-rpc, so just try it?

Comment: I already tried to do this and asked for friends that know GML and didn't work...

Comment: Then you would most likely be best of asking a question about a specific issue you're having with the implementation.